# How add to Visual Studio 2017 or 2019 old C++ (v110) compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

I need compile my C++ project with old compiler verison. I saw, that is possibly to add to new visual studio old compiler. I try to download and install some build kit and remote utility for VS 2020 (ver v110), but nothing changed. I expect in properties - platform toolset - new line - v110, but nothing happen.
What I shloud to download and install and what to do?

Comment: If you can find a source for the actual installer for an older version of VS, then maybe try that. But you'll probably have to 'repair' the VS2017/19 installation *afterwards*, so that it detects the presence of that older version - and thus enables the toolsets from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [VS2012](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/) platform toolset. In fact, you don't need to uninstall the redistributables. It's just that there may be installation errors．Also, if you unstall them, you could re-install them in [Microsoft Downloads](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Then, you could change v110 in `properties -> platform toolset`.

For the previous version of VS2012, you can go to download it on daffodil website.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the old Visual Studio 2012 to use the compiler in a newer Visual Studio (e.g. 2017). Therefore uninstall the redistributables ("Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable") to avoid errors.
Then you have to install the old Visual Studio 2012 and it's updates if required.
Afterward you will probably have to "repair" the newer Visual Studio Installations.

Comment: What do the redistributables have to do with this? You will break every installed program that relies on the VS2012 redistributable when you do this.

Comment: If you don't uninstall the redistributables the installation of Visual Studio possibly fails, so it can be helpful to uninstall them. The setup of Visual Studio will ask you if you want to install the redistributables again.